Custom tabs ripple effect is stopped when click has ended
I'm making some custom tabs, however the behaviour of the ripple effect is a bit weird when selecting the non-selected tab. The ripple effect only happens when the mouse click is down. Can one of you help with making the ripple effect complete its animation when clicked?
Stackblitz example
